# Alamofire 4 swift 3 Uploading MultipartFormData with header not posting

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, alamofire

I'm having a problem with my code and the new Alamofire 4 have searched the web for examples - no luck. My code skips the post method it's not calling to the URL:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{
        multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(tempUrl, withName: self.path)},
                     usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
                     to:posturl!,
                     method:.post,
                     headers: Oauthdata.uplodHeader ,
                     encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                        switch encodingResult {
                        case .success(let upload, _, _):
                            upload.responseJSON { response in
                                debugPrint(response)
                            }
                        case .failure(let encodingError):
                            print(encodingError)
                        }
    })} catch {
        print("Somethings not right")
}
```

Comment: What is `Oauthdata.uplodHeader` (sic)? also please format your code :)

Comment: Oauthdata.uplodHeader is a header from a struct i created for apis to be able to use in other classes im new to this and this is my 1st post on stack over flow please help

Comment: Yeah but what is your problem? That is not working? It would be interesting to see the oauthdata header, the actual value. Also try to not use `!`, use `guard let url = posturl else {return} instead`

Comment: not to be able to post to my endpoint no call is being made im trying to upload a recording to the end point also have paramiters i need to pass along with the upload im abit confused on the new structure please help 2 weeks now im stuck on one thing ...... this is my header seems               uplodHeader = [
            "Authorization":("\(TokenType) \(Token)" as AnyObject) as! String
        ]

Comment: your authHeader should probably be: `let authHeader: Dictionary<String, String> = ["Authorization" : "Bearer \(authToken)"` or something like that. Have you printed the header to see that it looks correctly formatted? with the correct authToken value?

Comment: uplodHeader: HTTPHeaders = [:]    thats how i did it in my struc thn init like i sent as above but its not making a call it just skips the .post part put a break point there so i would know i think  is more my structuring the one above thats wrong ..... header prints perfectly

Comment: what happens if you remove "usingThreshold"? It seems optional? https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-multipart-form-data

Comment: im not sure if this is good or bad but this is what im getting back    [Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."                                                               NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.}

Comment: Yes Transport security, Google it! :)

Comment: Googled it plist added all of that one final error you are alife saver brother um im getting that back           ParseException: Failed to parse authentication header:  something wrong

Comment: Please paste the full output of the error. I would suggest using this new feature to handle auth header: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#request-adapter

Comment: is it possible we can move this to a discussion ? and how to i make this question solved .. well its not now but with ur help it will be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the approach using `RequestAdapter` protocol, mentioned in [the docs](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#request-adapter):

```
class AccessTokenAdapter: RequestAdapter {
    private let accessToken: String

    init(accessToken: String) {
        self.accessToken = accessToken
    }

    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = urlRequest
        urlRequest.setValue("Bearer " + accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        return urlRequest
    }
}

class HTTPClient {

    func setupHeader(with authToken: String) {
        let sessionManager = SessionManager()
        sessionManager.adapter = AccessTokenAdapter(accessToken: authToken)
    }
}
```

Where `HTTPClient` is the class where you are performing this setup...

Comment: and how to i put it in my upload method ?

Comment: you call setupHeader after having logged in... when you actually have a valid token!

Comment: got it working thanks alot ..... now all i have to figure out is where to add params

Comment: Did you found out where to add params?